# How to use width in a table border?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` in my forum, but I just can't get the `width="100%"` to work with it.

Is it possible to set a width while using `cellpadding` or `cellspacing` in my CSS?

```css
.categories div.category td tr{
   padding: 80px;
   width: 500px; 
}
```

```
echo '
  <table class="categories">
    <caption>Category: ', $row2['category'], '</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <th colspan="3"><a href="create_music_sub.php?cat='.$row2['id'].'&admin='.$row2['admin'].'">
            Click here to Create Sub Category
          </a></th>
        </td>
      </tr><tr>
        <div class="category"><th scope="col">Category</th></div>
        <th scope="col">Creator</th>
        <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
      </tr>
    </thead><tbody>';
```

Comment: Snippet doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If what you meant is to set the table's width to 100%, this works. 
And as for the code you provided there were mistakes:

1. When you want to use a `th` you don't use a `td` with it.
2. The div.category should be inside the `tr > th` not wrapping it.
3. When you're posting a question please remove the php fragments and provide a working fiddle for us to be able to help you faster.

Please look at the code to see what I did differently. I think the problem was in your html

```css
table{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

tr, th, td{
  border:1px solid black;
}

td,th{
  padding: 10px;
}

/*If you want the last column to be smaller you can change one of them to a certain width*/

.creator{
  width:20%;
}
```

```html
<table class="categories">
 <caption>Category: 1</caption>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th colspan="3">
    <a href="">Click here to Create Sub Category</a>
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">
    <div class="category">Category</div>
   </th>
   <th scope="col">Creator</th>
   <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
  </tr>
    
    <tr>
   <th colspan="2" scope="col">
    <div class="category">Category</div>
   </th>
   <th scope="col">Creator</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>


<table class="categories">
 <caption>Category: 1</caption>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th colspan="3">
    <a href="">Click here to Create Sub Category</a>
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">
    <div class="category">Category</div>
   </th>
   <th scope="col">Creator</th>
   <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
  </tr>
    
    <tr>
   <th colspan="2" scope="col">
    <div class="category">Category</div>
   </th>
   <th scope="col" class="creator">Creator</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but the width property does not work with cellpadding or cellspacing.. how would I include a width with it? I need to use cellpadding i the css.. should i just use padding?

Comment: Yes you should use normal padding, I edited the CSS snippet. Have a look I added also a "colspan" on the 3rd row.

Comment: @musician0011 1st table only padding + colspan, 2nd table: with width + padding + colspan, I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks... So at least now I understand that the width only works for  the second table and not for the first... Cheers!